# Activar Input Segun Un select PHP SQL - SERVER

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Cordial Saludo.

Espero me puedan ayudar con el problema que tengo, o una idea de como llegar a realizar lo que quiero.

Les comento lo que deseo hacer:

1. Tengo un Select PHP - SQL:
   Contiene en la base de datos:  Id, Nombre, Campo1,Campo2,Campo3,Campo4,Campo5

Cada Campo1 hasta el Campo5, Contiene un Valor de SI o un valor de NO.

2.
El select estara cargado: Ejemplo:

```
<select>
<option>Seleccionar</option>
<option>Prueba</option>
</select>
```

El campo prueba, es el que esta en la base de datos, y contiene Id, Nombre, Campo1,Campo2,Campo3,Campo4,Campo5.

4. Tengo 5 Inputs.

Lo que quiero hacer es que si al seleccionar "Prueba" en el SELECT, Me active el input 1, si tiene un valor de "SI", Si no tiene si, el input debe quedar disabled.

Es la misma dinamica con los demas inputs.

No se como realizarlo, espero me puedan ayudar y espero que me hubieran entendido.

Asi cargo el Select:

```
 <?php
                    include'conexion.php';

                    $sql = "EXEC SP_COMBO_PAGADURIAS";
                    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
                    if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){
                    $menu="<select name='menu' onchange='getComboC(this)' class='form-control' id ='menu'>\n<option selected>Seleccionar:</option>";
                    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $menu.="\n<option value='".$row['Campo1']."'>".utf8_encode($row['Nombre'])."</option>";
                    }
                    $menu.="\n</select>";
                    echo $menu;
                    }
                ?>
```

Inputs:

```
 <?php

  for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++){
  switch ($i){

    case 0:

      $pos = strpos($row, 'SI');


        if($pos !== false ){

             echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

      }else{



             echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled name="uno" id="uno">';

      }

      break;


    case 1:

     $pos = strpos($Acceso, 'F');

        if($pos !== false ){

             echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

      }else{

             echo '<input type="text" disabled class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

      }


      break;

   case 2:

    $pos = strpos($Acceso, 'R');

        if($pos !== false ){

             echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

      }else{

             echo '<input type="text" disabled class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

       }


      break;


   case 3:
    $pos = strpos($Acceso, 'N');

       if($pos !== false ){

             echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

     }else{

             echo '<input type="text" disabled class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

     }

    break;

      case 4:
    $pos = strpos($Acceso, 'N');

       if($pos !== false ){

             echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

     }else{

             echo '<input type="text" disabled class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

     }

     break;

     case 5:
    $pos = strpos($Acceso, 'N');

       if($pos !== false ){

             echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

     }else{


             echo '<input type="text" disabled class="form-control" name="uno" id="uno">';

     }




} 

 }


?>
```

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer desde el front-end mediante javascript. Si es con JQuery revisa el evento **change** del **select**

Comment: Esto es lo que tengo, no se como hacerlo:

Answer (score 0):

Lo que queres es que al seleccionar "prueba" se vean los 5 input y que solo sean editables los que dicen si? - Bueno

Acá te dejo un php. Si no entendes decime.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prueba";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
         while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$campo1 = $row['campo1'];
$campo2 = $row['campo2'];
$campo3 = $row['campo3'];
$campo4 = $row['campo4'];
$campo5 = $row['campo5'];

if($campo1 == 'si'){
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("input1").readonly = false;'
}
if($campo2 == 'si'){
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("input2").readonly = false;'
}if($campo3 == 'si'){
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("input3").readonly = false;'
}if($campo4 == 'si'){
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("input4").readonly = false;'
}if($campo5 == 'si'){
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("input5").readonly = false;'
}
```

}

Comment: Si, pero los "SI", Son campos de una base de datos